# how to put left brace in equation?

Tags: braces

i want to write like this

```
        /ki    if 0<I<IO
       | 
t(i)= <
       |
        \c     if I>Io
```

here is curly bracket

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should use the `cases` environment. See the documentation of `amsmath`, § 3.7, Alignment building blocks. See also `mathtools`, § 3.4.3, More cases-like environments.

Comment: Irrespective of the left brace, I don't understand very well what the formula is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been suggested in the comments, it looks like a `cases` environment is what you need.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' environment
\begin{document}
\[
t(i) = 
\begin{cases}
k_i & \text{if $0<i<i_0$}\\
c   & \text{if $i>i_0$} 
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```